# How to query multiple databases in the same select query in clickhouse database?

Tags: database, query-optimization, clickhouse

I have a clickhouse database. It contains multiple databases. The tables inside the databases are identical.

For example DB1 has the table "Table1", DB2 also has the table "Table1" (Here the databases are different, Tables are also different but they have identical schema and contain similar type of information).

Is there a way that i can write a query to get the information from all the different tables from all the different databases optimally? Currently i am querying each table individually and doing an Union among them.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a special table with [Merge](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/merge/) engine (not to be confused with MergeTree). Querying it will do the the same `UNION ALL` transparently. It does not support spanning through multiple databases though, so you still might end up having multiple of those or moving the tables into one db.

Comment: Well there is a way to span through multiple databases. Just set up multi Merge engines and chain them one after another :)

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to create one more DB:

```
create database <your_db_name> on cluster <your_cluster_name>;
```

Then create a [Merge](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/merge/) table for each of you existing DB:

```
CREATE TABLE <your_db_name>.<merge_table_name> On cluster <your_cluster_name> (<fields list you need to deal with>)  ENGINE=Merge(<existing_db_name>, '<regex>');
```

Create a [View](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/create/#create-view) for each of the Merge tables (using a view you can execute any aggregate functions, group by and etc.):

```
CREATE VIEW <your_db_name>.view_<merge_table_name> on cluster <your_cluster_name> (<list of fields>) AS SELECT <list of fields> FROM <your_db_name>.<merge_table_name>;
```

Finally create a "result" Merge table that combines all the views newly created:

```
CREATE TABLE <your_db_name>.<result_table_name> on cluster <your_cluster_name> (<list of fields>)  ENGINE=Merge(<your_db_name>, '<regex>');
```

> Name the tables and views in such a way that your regular expression matches all you need and make sure you avoid loops.